"Adding 'Items Remaining' and 'Approximate Time Remaining' to Sitecore Publishing Wizard Interface"

Hi, I would like to add two item extensions to the Publishing Wizard interface in Sitecore. Specifically, I want to display 'Items Remaining' and 'Approximate Time Remaining' below the 'Processed Items' section. I have attached an image for reference.
Could anyone please guide me on how to implement this?
